# SQL Moving Row to Identical Table WITHOUT auto-increment (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, procedure

I have two tables - "RENTED" and "HISTORY." Once an item is returned I need to move it to the "HISTORY" table using a procedure. The tables are identical in every way. The primary key is just a number, but is NOT auto-incremented. When I try to move a row from Rented to History, I get a clash because the primary keys both have the number 2 for an ID number. I know I just need to find the max value of the primary key in the HISTORY table, then add the row after. Seemed easy, ended up being hard to do. Lastly, I delete the row from the RENTED Table, which I am able to do. Please assist me with the row movement.  Thanks!

Also, I looked at some other similar code samples/answers here, but didn't find a solution quite yet.

```
Create Procedure spMoveToHistory
@RENTED_OUT_NUM bigint

AS

Begin

  Insert Into HISTORY
  Select *
  From RENTED_OUT
  Where RENTED_OUT_NUM = @RENTED_OUT_NUM
    Select @RENTED_OUT_NUM = (MAX(HISTORY_NUM)+1)
    From HISTORY

Delete From RENTED
Where RENTED_OUT_NUM = @RENTED_OUT_NUM


End
```

So in this procedure, I just want to enter the number 2 and take the 2nd record in the RENTED table and move over to the HISTORY table's next available row. See below for better visualization of the tables (a few columns omitted)

```
**RENTED TABLE:** 
RENTED_OUT_ID (PK) | ITEM_NAME | ITEM_DESC | DATE_RENTED | DATE_RETURNED
1                      data         data       data           data
2   move this          data         data       data           data         
3                      data         data       data           data         


**HISTORY TABLE:**
HISTORY_NUM   (PK) | ITEM_NAME | ITEM_DESC | DATE_RENTED | DATE_RETURNED
1                      data         data       data           data         
2                      data         data       data           data            
->   INSERT HERE
```

Comment: It is not possible if you are maintaining HISTORY_NUM column in HISTORY table as primary key

Comment: create a new auto incremented column in HISTORY table which will act as primary key and remove the primary key attribute from HISTORY_NUM column

Comment: @mudassirhasan That can't be right. All i'd have to do is find the MAX(HISTORY_NUM) and increment it by 1, then place the data in that row?

Comment: I can't add or remove columns in my tables. Is there a different way to do this in a procedure?

Comment: but then you are loosing rented_out_id of record  being moved from RENTED to HISTORY table

Comment: @mudassirhasan It is okay if the rented_out_id is changed to a different digit in this case. That isn't important once the item is returned. This isn't a real database, just for testing.

Comment: @mudassirhasan I could just take all the columns as parameters but i'm just trying to do it as one parameter :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the OUTPUT INTO clause to insert the deleted record into the history table in one go. The syntax will be this:

```
declare @max_id bigint
select @max_id = max(HISTORY_NUM)+1 from history

DELETE FROM rented 
OUTPUT @max_id
     , DELETED.ITEM_NAME
     , DELETED.ITEM_DESC
     , DELETED.DATE_RENTED
     , DELETED.DATE_RETURNED
INTO history
WHERE RENTED_OUT_NUM = @RENTED_OUT_NUM
```

Comment: Wow, this is great. I'll test this and accept your answer sometime tomorrow if it works this easily. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring while inserting in `HISTORY_NUM` column of `HISTORY` table because its a primary key and cannot take repetitive value of `RENTED_OUT_ID` column of `RENTED` table.
So find max existing `HISTORY_NUM` column value and increment by one to insert new record every time while moving records.

```
Create Procedure spMoveToHistory
@RENTED_OUT_NUM bigint

AS

Begin


DECLARE @HISTORY_ID BIGINT
SELECT @HISTORY_ID = MAX(HISTORY_NUM) FROM HISTORY

Insert Into HISTORY(HISTORY_NUM, ITEM_NAME, ITEM_DESC, DATE_RENTED,  DATE_RETURNED)
Select @HISTORY_ID + 1 , ITEM_NAME, ITEM_DESC, DATE_RENTED,  DATE_RETURNED
From RENTED_OUT
Where RENTED_OUT_ID = @RENTED_OUT_NUM



Delete From RENTED
Where RENTED_OUT_NUM = @RENTED_OUT_NUM


End
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, except not quite as smoothly. I very much appreciate your time in this!! However, I less code is always better, so i'll be accepting the answer below. Once again, thank you Mudassir.